# Can I have access to props using shallow render?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

I wanted to test if my component get props that I passed in shallow render:

```
const defaultProps = {
  testString: 'string',
  testArr: [],
  checkData: jest.fn(),
  activePage: false,
};

const wrapper = shallow(<Component { ...defaultProps } />);

test("should load component with passed props", () => {
  expect(wrapper.props()).toEqual(defaultProps);
});
```

but I got an error and in console I see all child components of the tested component. I used mount and test pass properly but I'm wondering why shallow render cannot pass props properly?

Comment: Have you tried wrapper.instance().props?

Comment: https://airbnb.io/enzyme/docs/api/ShallowWrapper/props.html

Comment: Can you put the error you got here?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working example, you can access the props of component using [.props() => Object](https://airbnb.io/enzyme/docs/api/ShallowWrapper/props.html).

`index.tsx`:

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class SomeComponent extends Component {
  render() {
    return <div {...this.props}></div>;
  }
}

export default SomeComponent;
```

`index.spec.tsx`:

```js
import React from 'react';
import SomeComponent from './';
import { shallow } from 'enzyme';

describe('SomeComponent', () => {
  it('should load component with passed props', () => {
    const defaultProps = {
      testString: 'string',
      testArr: [],
      checkData: jest.fn(),
      activePage: false
    };
    const wrapper = shallow(<SomeComponent {...defaultProps}></SomeComponent>);
    expect(wrapper.props()).toEqual(defaultProps);
  });
});
```

Unit test result with 100% coverage

```sh
 PASS  src/stackoverflow/56011077/index.spec.tsx
  SomeComponent
    ✓ should load component with passed props (8ms)

-----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
File       |  % Stmts | % Branch |  % Funcs |  % Lines | Uncovered Line #s |
-----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
All files  |      100 |      100 |      100 |      100 |                   |
 index.tsx |      100 |      100 |      100 |      100 |                   |
-----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        5.585s, estimated 11s
```

Source code: https://github.com/mrdulin/jest-codelab/tree/master/src/stackoverflow/56011077